# SmartWatch 2: failed to show widget and control when compiling apk with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, sony-smartwatch

I created a control extension and two widget extensions for SmartWatch 2 with Sony add-on SDK v3. If I compiled my apk with Progurad, I won't see my app listed in SmartWatch 2's installed applications list. In addition, no my widgets found when editing the clock face.

I am sure that the problem is caused by Proguard as the function works well when I compile the apk without using Proguard.

I read all SDK documentation and do not find any words about which proguard rules should be added.

I finally find out a solution (may not be the best but it works). Please see my answer if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problems happens when you are creating a widget extension (a widget that can be added to the clock face) and compiling the apk with Proguard.

You can fix the problem by adding the following rule in your proguard configuration file.

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.widget.WidgetExtension { public <init>(...); }
```